# Internet Connection lost when setting Charles proxy on Android

Tags: android, security, charles-proxy

I am trying to set charles proxy on Android 8.0( S8 ). I have installed the root certificate-> Changed WIFI settings to charles proxy settings. But After connecting to proxy, Internet connection is lost. Tried multiple times. Is there any other security certificate I need to install for Android 8.0. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems Android device - Charles Proxy - internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752081/problems-android-device-charles-proxy-internet-connection)

Answer (score 3):

The sequence of steps is really important:

1. Connect the Android device and the computer that running Charles to the same LAN (WiFi) network
2. Start Charles
3. Then set the Charles machine LAN IP as manual proxy on your phone. Open the list of Wifi connections, then touch and hold the connected network, and select ***Modify network***.

   - Proxy: ***Manual***
   - Proxy hostname: Open the ***Help > Local IP Address*** menu in Charles and paste into it the address displayed
   - Proxy port: ***8888*** (This is the default value that can be changed in the ***Proxy > Proxy Settings*** menu.)
4. Open a browser on your phone and make some network traffic
5. After that you have to click into the Charles app window. You will see a confirmation dialog that asking you to allow network traffic from the mobile device, press ***Allow***.
6. After all, open the **https://chls.pro/ssl** URL on your device and install the ***.pem*** file for ***VPN and apps*** (Use Chrome browser on Android, and Safari for iOS devices.)

### Troubleshooting

- When Charles is the background, the confirmation dialog will not be visible automatically, you have to activate (bring back to the foreground) the Charles application window to see it.
- To check the device connection permission, go to ***Proxy > Access Control Settings***. You should also see its LAN IP on the list.
- To getting your Android phone LAN IP address open the Dialer and enter: `*#*#4636#*#*`, then select ***Wi-Fi information > WiFi status*** and refresh stats.

Comment: after step 3 it shows that there is no internet and I cannot browse anything

Comment: @Donki have you should after step 3?

Comment: @Donki Go to Proxy tab on Charles and uncheck Windows Proxy option.

Comment: the same issue happens in the Android device/emulator while using proxyman. Unable to trace the issue. Did any had a successful connecting Android with proxyman in MacOS?

Comment: If you lost the Internet connection as soon as set the HTTP Proxy to Charles or Proxyman, it might be the firewall that blocks all incoming connections. Please allow the app in Firewall setting. Read more at https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/my-ios-devices-couldnt-connect-to-proxyman-via-proxy

Comment: This still doesnt work. Traffic to https gets blocked when SSL Proxying is on. Also order of steps 1 to 3 doesnt matter

Comment: same issue i am also facing after connect charles internet connection gone

Answer (score 0):

In `Charles`:

1. I selected `Tools menu > Allow List`
2. Unchecked `Enable Allow List`
3. Clicked Ok

This worked for me to get internet with the proxy set & finally was able to download the certified.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone who is still looking for answer then try these steps. It worked for me ☺️
When you enter proxy, there will be one more option that is "Bypass for" in this field enter * as value, and thnx me later.

Comment: where can i find this option? this is not in the "Proxy" menu of charles

Comment: This does allow you to navigate the web, but it bypasses all proxies, including the proxy you just set up for Charles. Which renders Charles useless.