# Internet does not work on ios/Android after connecting to Charles proxy

Tags: charles-proxy

1. I have installed the root certificates on my Mac and trusted it as well.
2. Set up the manual proxy on Android and iOS with same IP address as the Mac.
3. On Charles disabled the allow list.
4. Enable the SSL proxy using `*`.

I followed all the possible steps but still on both the devices, internet does not work.
Can anybody help me with this? I am totally stuck at this point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems Android device - Charles Proxy - internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752081/problems-android-device-charles-proxy-internet-connection)