# Getting no internet after Android proxy config

Tags: android, debugging, proxy, charles-proxy, android-debug

I am trying to do proxy configuration in Redmi Note 7 Android 9.
I have connected my Macbook and Device to the same wifi network, after doing manual configuration for Proxy IP address:`192.168.XX.XX`, Port `8888` I am not able to the browser itself.
Getting error message that I am offline on Google chrome.

I have also tried installing the SSL root certificate in mac and tried to install the same in Android phone as well as I was not able to launch `chls.pro/ssl` in my device.

Not able to install `.pem` certificate also, so converted into .cert and installed in device. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296421/internet-connection-lost-when-setting-charles-proxy-on-android.  Issue is similar to this, but troubleshooting steps are not working

Comment: This is not off-topic here but I would say that on superuser, it would have been answered by now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @BhavyaGupta, I raise the same on Super user as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems Android device - Charles Proxy - internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752081/problems-android-device-charles-proxy-internet-connection)